# importing a python variable instead of manual inputting data to plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python script which reads a csv file and uses a variable to return a mean for each column. I have checked around online and asked friends in real life but how do I call this variable, named:
`transformed_means = ((specified_column_means / 1_000_000).round(0) *1_000_000).round(-5)`

Constructing a basic bar chart on the x axis I want to just call each mean associated with the `specified_column_means` variable instead of manually ploting them as inputs like you do in matplotlib.

Comment: It's not clear what you have and what you're trying to to change. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

To plot the means with error bars in Matplotlib, you can use the errorbar function to display the mean and standard deviation for each column. Here's an example of how to achieve this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Assuming you have the means and standard deviations calculated
means = [...]  # List of means for each column
std_devs = [...]  # List of standard deviations for each column

# Plotting the bar chart with error bars
plt.bar(x=range(len(means)), height=means, yerr=std_devs, capsize=5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: So I don't call the variable? This is still like manual input in the list "means = [...]" no?

Comment: But you can always calculate it using `pandas `

Comment: I did, I read the csv file using pandas and did the mean there.